# negative distances with cv::HoughLines?

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

I'm using cv::HoughLines to get the Lines found in an Matrix. The Matrix is ok (I know this beacause I get an Output. Ist an 8-Bit Integer Map with 0 for black and 255 for white points).

The problem is, that I get good angular values but partly negative distance values. Is this possible? Distances are always positive I thought.

Answer (score 0):

According to wikipedia's hough transform article;

if your theta range is theta>= 0 && theta<=pi, then your rho values may be negative numbers.
But if your theta range is theta>=0 && theta>>(2*pi), then your rho values must have positive value.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform)